# Recyclerview crop last and first items shadow

Tags: android, xml, user-interface

Recyclerview crop first and last items shadows and i cant't fix it with any attributes.
I have a such xml screen:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".screens.view.CreateRequestFragment">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/createRequestScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/sendRequestButton"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <!-- ... some elements inside scrollview -->

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/usersRecyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_m"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/selectUsersTitle" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sendRequestButton"
        style="@style/OnDutyButtonStart"
        android:text="Send Request"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_m"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:text="Send Request" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

In this case i get cropped last and first items shadows:

[image]

but i need it like this:

[image]

If i add margin or padding - i get the same with blank white space and always cropped shadows.

Comment: Padding should work if you also set `android:clipToPadding="false"` on the `<RecyclerView>`.

Comment: use this
https://github.com/irfaan008/OnePageSigninSignup

Comment: If you're using `CardView` for your item, you should set item margin the same value as its elevation.